# Calling push notification registration from outside app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Okay so I have an app where I want to implement push notifications. The problem is that I want to use the users username to help identify which device they are sending the notifications too. But when it is called in the delegate sometimes the users are not logged in yet so the app crashes. The code is in this method

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    currentInstallation[@"installationUser"] = [[PFUser currentUser]username];
    // here we add a column to the installation table and store the current user’s ID
    // this way we can target specific users later

    // while we’re at it, this is a good place to reset our app’s badge count
    // you have to do this locally as well as on the parse server by updating
    // the PFInstallation object
    if (currentInstallation.badge != 0) {
        currentInstallation.badge = 0;
        [currentInstallation saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // Handle error here with an alert…
            }
            else {
                // only update locally if the remote update succeeded so they always match
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
                NSLog(@"updated badge");
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

So I need this NOT to be called if the user has not logged in yet but then I want it to be called every time. I am getting confused about how to do this. Let me know if you have any ideas, thanks!

Comment: see my answer for review. it's best to put this in your main view controller inside the viewDidAppear method. Ensure all your notification tokens are set and methods are invoked properly. Here is their documentation for anyone else looking : https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so please allow me the credit for correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't normally call this in `applicationDidBecomeActive` I see you've read up on the docs a little bit but it's real easy:

```
if (![PFUser currentUser]) { // No user logged in : this is all you need because in applicationDidRegistreForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken should have set the user or installation ID already
//Enter data
} else {
// User logged in
}
```

NOTE : This is best to be used in your main view controllers `viewDidAppear` method. Review their documentation for future guidance : https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views